# Converting inline SVG to SVG file (to make it compatible with Safari)

Tags: svg, safari

I can't get Safari to display as an inline SVG. Because of this, I want to convert my inline SVG to an SVG file and embed it using an element, but I don't know how to do this.

The code is in this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n01n5vv6/

Its also down here:

```
<svg color="#2C2F33" fill="#FFFFFF" width="125" height="125" viewBox="0 0 250 250" class="previewbox" style="transform: rotate(0deg); background-color: rgb(44, 47, 51);"><g><a href="https://discord.gg/tMjV4ZM"><path d="M0,0 L0,250 L250,0 Z" fill="#FFFFFF"></path></a></g> <g class="discord-corner"><svg color="#2C2F33" fill="#FFFFFF" width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 48 48" class="discord-logo-container"><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="currentfill"></rect> <defs><g><defs><path id="discord-def-face" fill="currentcolor" d="M40,12C40,12,35.415,8.412,30,8L29.512,8.976C34.408,10.174,36.654,11.891,39,14C34.955,11.935,30.961,10,24,10S13.045,11.935,9,14C11.346,11.891,14.018,9.985,18.488,8.976L18,8C12.319,8.537,8,12,8,12S2.879,19.425,2,34C7.162,39.953,15,40,15,40L16.639,37.815C13.857,36.848,10.715,35.121,8,32C11.238,34.45,16.125,37,24,37S36.762,34.45,40,32C37.285,35.121,34.143,36.848,31.361,37.815L33,40C33,40,40.838,39.953,46,34C45.121,19.425,40,12,40,12Z"></path> <g id="discord-def-face-eyes"><path id="discord-def-face-left-eye" fill="currentfill" d="M17.5,30C15.567,30,14,28.209,14,26C14,23.791,15.567,22,17.5,22S21,23.791,21,26C21,28.209,19.433,30,17.5,30Z"></path> <path id="discord-def-face-right-eye" fill="currentfill" d="M30.5,30C28.567,30,27,28.209,27,26C27,23.791,28.567,22,30.5,22S34,23.791,34,26C34,28.209,32.433,30,30.5,30Z"></path></g></defs> <g id="discordFaceID66"><use href="#discord-def-face"></use> <g id="discord-logo-eyes"><mask id="mask-right-eye-wink"><ellipse fill="#FFFFFF" ry="15" rx="15" cy="39.7" cx="35"></ellipse> <ellipse fill="#000000" ry="15" rx="15" cy="40.5" cx="34"></ellipse></mask> <mask id="mask-eyes-angry"><rect height="48" width="48" y="0" x="0" fill="#FFFFFF"></rect> <rect transform="rotate(45 24,14.5)" height="24" width="24" y="2.5" x="12" fill="#000000"></rect></mask> <g class="discord-eyes"><use xlink:href="#discord-def-face-eyes"></use></g></g></g> <mask id="mask-outer-layer"><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#FFFFFF"></rect> <circle r="42%" cx="50%" cy="50%" fill="#000000"></circle></mask> <mask id="mask-middle-layer"><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#000000"></rect> <circle r="43%" cx="50%" cy="50%" fill="#FFFFFF"></circle> <circle r="32%" cx="50%" cy="50%" fill="#000000"></circle></mask> <mask id="mask-inner-layer"><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#000000"></rect> <circle r="32%" cx="50%" cy="50%" fill="#FFFFFF"></circle></mask></g></defs> <g class="discord-logo softshake-animation"><use class="discord-original" xlink:href="#discordFaceID66"></use></g> <a href="https://url.com"><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill-opacity="0"></rect></a> <!----></svg></g></svg>

<style type='text/css'>* { font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; } .discord-logo { transform: scale(0.7); transform-origin: 24px 24px; } .discord-corner { transform: rotate(-45deg); transform-origin: 60px 60px; }.discord-logo.softshake-animation .discord-original { transform-origin: 24px 24px; } .discord-logo-container:hover .softshake-animation .discord-original, .animated .softshake-animation .discord-original { animation: softshake 2000ms linear forwards; } @keyframes softshake { 0%,66%,100% {transform:rotate( 0deg)} 3% {transform:rotate(-18.0deg)} 6% {transform:rotate( 14.4deg)} 9% {transform:rotate(-11.5deg)} 12% {transform:rotate( 9.21deg)} 15% {transform:rotate(-7.37deg)} 18% {transform:rotate( 5.89deg)} 21% {transform:rotate(-4.71deg)} 24% {transform:rotate( 3.77deg)} 27% {transform:rotate(-3.02deg)} 30% {transform:rotate( 2.41deg)} 33% {transform:rotate(-1.93deg)} 36% {transform:rotate( 1.54deg)} 39% {transform:rotate(-1.23deg)} 42% {transform:rotate( 0.99deg)} 45% {transform:rotate(-0.79deg)} 48% {transform:rotate( 0.63deg)} 51% {transform:rotate(-0.50deg)} 54% {transform:rotate( 0.40deg)} 57% {transform:rotate(-0.32deg)} 60% {transform:rotate( 0.25deg)} 63% {transform:rotate(-0.20deg)} }</style>
```

Comment: You've said what you want, what's stopping you? This is a question and answer site and you haven't asked a question i.e. said precisely why you can't do what you want to do.

Comment: Oh, I'm so sorry. I'm new around here. What I'm asking is how to convert inline code to a SVG file, I don't know how to do this.

Comment: save it as a separate file and add the missing namespace attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Safari does not yet support SVG 2 style of doing away with `xlink` namespaces, so your workaround wouldn't work.

First add the namespaces attributes to the `svg` tag...

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
```

Then namespace your `href` tags...

```
 <a xlink:href="...">
```

You can see it working in Safar here: https://jsfiddle.net/n01n5vv6/2/

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean here by namspacing the href of an <a> tag. My SVGs already have the xmlns namespaces as you pointed out but dont work in safari, im not sure which href tags to modify on my existing code to make svgs work now on safari... any clarifications?

Comment: @xunux This answer was for an old version of Safari which didn't display the SVG unless there was a namespace, current Safari now displays OP's SVG without trouble. I would suggest you ask a new question and post your SVG code to be able to debug the problem.